# WebCore: Worker: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when connecting Safari debugger to an Ionic 3 project

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, safari, ionic3

I've installed my app on my iPhone. It runs perfectly fine until I open the Safari debugger, then I get this error:

```
WebCore: Worker (15): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

It seems to be related to this:

```
WebCore`WebCore::WorkerMessagingProxy::postMessageToPageInspector:
```

I'm using:

- iPhone SE, iOS 10.3.3
- Xcode 8.3.3
- Ionic 3.10.3
- Cordova 7.0.1
- MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015), MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
- Safari 10.1.2

Here's the crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 4839F7DB-5E07-472E-841D-934A59E28CF0
CrashReporter Key:   568cac6944ead7d541e3f06c919bd81dbc091554
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,4
Process:             MyApp [379]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C608AECA-4665-4BD3-9FD8-CF103A463FCD/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          io.ionic.starter
Version:             0.0.1 (0.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           io.ionic.starter [500]


Date/Time:           2017-09-14 15:15:11.1392 -0500
Launch Time:         2017-09-14 15:14:56.8841 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  11

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181523224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018152309c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f4e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f2ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182422da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   GraphicsServices                0x0000000183e8d074 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                           0x00000001886ddc9c UIApplicationMain + 208
7   MyApp                           0x00000001000d872c main (main.m:32)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018143159c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181541a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816071a4 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181541a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001816071a4 _pthread_wqthread + 1260
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181541a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606fd0 _pthread_wqthread + 792
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181523224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018152309c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f4e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f2ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182422da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x0000000182f3ddb4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x0000000182f5eb84 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x0000000189067830 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018303b318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606ca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181523224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018152309c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f4e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f2ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182422da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182c2fdf4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6   Foundation                      0x000000018303b318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181541314 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001814608b0 nanosleep + 212
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000180f713c4 std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&) + 80
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dd6d2c void std::__1::this_thread::sleep_for<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> > const&) + 76
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dd5d6c bmalloc::waitUntilFalse(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, bool&) + 128
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dd5ba8 bmalloc::Heap::scavenge(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 60
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dd5a50 bmalloc::Heap::concurrentScavenge() + 120
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dd6e30 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 92
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dd6d5c std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<std::__1::mutex, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::mutex> >::~__shared_ptr_emplace() + 0
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dd700c void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 92
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a9e3e4 WTF::HashMap<WTF::String, WTF::RefPtr<Inspector::InspectorValue>, WTF::StringHash, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::String>, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<Inspector::InspectorValue> > >::find(WTF::String const&) const + 88
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a9e028 Inspector::InspectorObjectBase::getValue(WTF::String const&, WTF::RefPtr<Inspector::InspectorValue>&) const + 52
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a9e028 Inspector::InspectorObjectBase::getValue(WTF::String const&, WTF::RefPtr<Inspector::InspectorValue>&) const + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a50798 Inspector::BackendDispatcher::dispatch(WTF::String const&) + 172
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186cd5774 ___ZN9Inspector24RemoteConnectionToTarget19sendMessageToTargetEP8NSString_block_invoke + 144
5   WebCore                         0x00000001880c3488 HandleRunSource(void*) + 704
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f542c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f4d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001824f29a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182422da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
10  WebCore                         0x00000001870f4d3c RunWebThread(void*) + 456
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  WebCore: AsyncFileStream
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181540e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181608814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018642a9a4 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 80
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dbda68 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2256
4   WebCore                         0x0000000187266108 bool WTF::ConditionBase::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 172
5   WebCore                         0x0000000187266d1c std::__1::unique_ptr<WTF::Function<void ()>, std::__1::default_delete<WTF::Function<void ()> > > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WTF::Function<void ()> const&)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WTF::Function<void ()> const&)&&, WTF::WallTime) + 144
6   WebCore                         0x0000000187266c44 std::__1::__function::__func<WebCore::callOnFileThread(WTF::Function<void ()>&&)::$_0::operator()() const::'lambda'(), std::__1::allocator<WebCore::callOnFileThread(WTF::Function<void ()>&&)::$_0::operator()() const::'lambda'()>, void ()>::operator()() + 80
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426f7c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426e8c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  IndexedDatabase Server
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181540e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181608814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018642a9a4 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 80
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dbda68 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2256
4   WebCore                         0x0000000187266108 bool WTF::ConditionBase::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 172
5   WebCore                         0x00000001876a15ac WTF::CrossThreadQueue<WTF::CrossThreadTask>::waitForMessage() + 116
6   WebCore                         0x000000018769f6d4 WebCore::IDBServer::IDBServer::databaseThreadEntry(void*) + 120
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426f7c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426e8c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  WebCore: Worker
Thread 11 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x000000018812b2c8 WebCore::WorkerMessagingProxy::postMessageToPageInspector(WTF::String const&) + 36
1   WebCore                         0x000000018812b2c4 WebCore::WorkerMessagingProxy::postMessageToPageInspector(WTF::String const&) + 32
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a94660 Inspector::FrontendRouter::sendResponse(WTF::String const&) const + 56
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a505b8 Inspector::BackendDispatcher::sendResponse(long, WTF::RefPtr<Inspector::InspectorObject>&&) + 352
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a72f40 Inspector::RuntimeBackendDispatcher::enable(long, WTF::RefPtr<Inspector::InspectorObject>&&) + 152
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a7058c Inspector::RuntimeBackendDispatcher::dispatch(long, WTF::String const&, WTF::Ref<Inspector::InspectorObject>&&) + 548
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186a50f68 Inspector::BackendDispatcher::dispatch(WTF::String const&) + 2172
7   WebCore                         0x000000018812c814 WebCore::WorkerRunLoop::runInMode(WebCore::WorkerGlobalScope*, WebCore::ModePredicate const&, WebCore::WorkerRunLoop::WaitMode) + 436
8   WebCore                         0x000000018812c5fc WebCore::WorkerRunLoop::run(WebCore::WorkerGlobalScope*) + 100
9   WebCore                         0x000000018812fe04 WebCore::WorkerThread::workerThread() + 980
10  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426f7c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
11  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426e8c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  WTF::AutomaticThread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181540e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181608814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018642a9e8 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dbda68 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2256
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018698f9d8 bool WTF::ConditionBase::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 172
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dad760 std::__1::__function::__func<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() + 204
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426f7c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426e8c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  WTF::AutomaticThread
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181540e1c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181608814 _pthread_cond_wait + 640
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018642a9e8 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 148
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dbda68 WTF::ParkingLot::parkConditionallyImpl(void const*, WTF::ScopedLambda<bool ()> const&, WTF::ScopedLambda<void ()> const&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 2256
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018698f9d8 bool WTF::ConditionBase::waitUntil<WTF::Lock>(WTF::Lock&, WTF::TimeWithDynamicClockType const&) + 172
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186dad760 std::__1::__function::__func<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&)::$_0, std::__1::allocator<WTF::AutomaticThread::start(WTF::Locker<WTF::LockBase> const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() + 204
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426f7c WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 212
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186426e8c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 24
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160968c _pthread_body + 240
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018160959c _pthread_body + 0
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181606cb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x000000016e842b88   x2: 0x000000018812b3c4   x3: 0x000000011111a490
    x4: 0x000000016e842a10   x5: 0x0000000000000060   x6: 0x7d313a226469222c   x7: 0x0000000033dc45e9
    x8: 0x00000001a88e6808   x9: 0x0000000000000002  x10: 0x0000000000000016  x11: 0x0000000000000040
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x00000000000e7f00
   x16: 0x0000000181600d60  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016e842b88  x21: 0x0000000111369200  x22: 0x000000010fa68040  x23: 0x0000000110727948
   x24: 0x0000000110727600  x25: 0x000000000000003f  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000066016499
   x28: 0x0000000000000018   fp: 0x000000016e842b30   lr: 0x000000018812b2c4
    sp: 0x000000016e842af0   pc: 0x000000018812b2c8 cpsr: 0x80000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of web worker due to some Safari error. Try commenting out your web worker piece.

Comment: There isn't a web worker in my code, but it could be part of the Ionic framework. If it is, then I guess I can't use that framework w/ the Safari Debugger.